# link back to full page from a mobile version

Tags: iphone, redirect, mobile, user-agent

I would like to forward iphone users to a mobile version of my site with apache's `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (...)`

My question is, how would I redirect visitors of the mobile site back to the full site? Since they're on a mobile device, they'd just get re-routed to the mobile site again right?

Cheers,
Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redirect to a page that sets a cookie value, then redirects back to the main page again.  Then you can do a [cookie-based rewrite](http://www.issociate.de/board/post/313532/Cookie-Based_Rewrite.html) - if the cookie is present, don't rewrite the URL.  If it's not present, do the rewrite.

The benefit of this, other than not having to append a GET variable to the URL, is that your user's preference is stored for future visits.  If he/she prefers the full format of the site that's what they will see the next time they visit.

Comment: +1. If you _don't_ want the user's preference saved for future visits, you can use a session cookie instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are using for web programing add a call. For example with php you could do `http://www.example.com/index.php?mobile=usefull` and add a header check. If that is present don't redirect.